# Variable ember-cli asset fingerprint prepend value

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to setup a cdn url in ember-cli, however I want the actual url to vary between environments.

```
// ember-cli-build.js

 var app = new EmberApp({
   fingerprint: {
     prepend: 'https://subdomain.cloudfront.net/' // want this to be variable between envs
     // prepend: 'https://' + process.env.ASSET_HOST + '/' <- this is what I want
   }
 });
```

I tried adding an environment variable to `process.env`, but that doesn't appear to exist the way it does if I were to access it on `config/environment.js`.

Is there a way to have a variable like this in my `ember-cli-build.js` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that this was, in fact, actually working when I deployed my code.  To get it working locally I added this line to the top of my `ember-cli-build.js`:

`require('dotenv').config({path: '../.env'});`